# ncmpcpp freezes at 2 Filesystem browser, 5 Playlist editor and 7 Output selector

Tags: linux, arch-linux, freeze, mpd

I'm using Arch Linux, and I was able to config ncmpcpp to work about three months ago. However today when I open it and press `2` for the Filesystem Browser it freezes while the CPU seems to be working hard (making loud noise). I can not switch to other tabs including back to `1` (Current Playlist). Same problem occurs for `5` (Playlist editor) and `7` (Output selector)

What can possibly caused this and how can I troubleshoot?

Things I tried but didn't help:

1. Changing the music directory to a much smaller one with about 10 songs and no sub directories
2. Renaming file `database` to `data.old` in the hope ncmpcpp will recreate the database
3. Inspecting file `log` in `$HOME/.config/mpd` - it has no record since three months ago.
4. Restarting `mpd.service`
5. Update mpd and ncmpcpp to the latest version (0.20.4 and 0.7.7 respectively)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the reason it freezes is because I `enable`d `mpd.service` globally, which presumably reads the default root configuration `/etc/mpd.conf` and causes the freezing. Why would root configuration be a problem? I don't know.

Instead I excute `systemctl --user mpd.service` and it works again.

See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mpd#Autostart_with_systemd

Three months ago it worked because I started mpd directly by typing `mpd` in command line when I logged in as a user.

Comment: This is probably obvious for most, but one also needs a config file at `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/mpd/mpd.conf` (usually `~/.config/mpd/mpd.conf`), `~/.mpd/mpd.conf` or `~/.mpdconf`.